# Create a Mobile Web User Control

Tags: mobile, controls

I am making mobile web pages to be accessed by smartphones and such.

I do not see either Mobile Web Form, or Mobile Web User Control in the list of installed templates in Visual Studio.

I probably need some mobile toolkit or something like that, but I can never find what I am looking for on MSDN.  Anyone know what I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downloading the **[Mobile Web Application Template](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/attachment/4776222.ashx)** for Visual Studio.

Source: [http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2008/04/01/mobile-web-forms-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20210126183113/http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2008/04/01/mobile-web-forms-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx)

Comment: Thank you!
I knew it was going to be something fairly simple like that. Why does MSDN suck so badly?